# X-Forwarded-Proto header being sent as http even if set the value value to https in nginx

Tags: nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I have configured X-Forwarded-Proto to https in my reverse proxy configuration , even then the X-Forwarded-Proto is shown as http.

Will the X-Forwarded-Proto header be configured by default if we dont set one

my reverse proxy configuration is something like this

```
location ~ ^/test {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port; 
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://test
}
```